# Own DynDNS for home server

Tags: home-server, dynamic-dns

I have two servers, one dedicated server with a static ip adress and one home server in my flat with a dynamic ip adress, which is renewed every 24 hours.

Currently I'm using the free service from freedns.afraid.org which works fine most of the time, but sometimes isn't available. The IP adress from freedns.afraid.org gets refreshed through my router, which has a setting for that service.

Now to my question: Is there an easy way to use one of my domains to always point at my home server? Can I set up a similar service like freedns.afraid.org on my dedicated server?

The home server is a HP Proliant Server with Ubuntu Server 16.04.1
The dedicated server is running Debian 8.5

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is of course possible. The specifics depend on your own domain’s DNS service (you need to be able to specify A and NS records) and whether you still want your router to do it – if it’s even possible to set up a custom dynamic DNS service. So please check those requirements.

Comment: What is the OS of your server? You could use something like this https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/

Comment: I have tried noip before but it requires that I verify my adress every few days. I want to host my own solution, if possible. @DanielB It doesn't have to be updated with the router, if you know any package or service I can use on the client-side (the home server) it would be appreciated. I've updated the question with system information.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish your original question (point your own domain name to your home) is to use a CNAME record on your own domain to the DynDNS service.

For example:

```
home.yourdomainname.org. IN CNAME yourdyndnsrecord.freedns.afraid.org.
```

Then users can just use home.yourdomainname.org and their computer will follow this to yourdyndnsrecord.freedns.afraid.org (which is for most intents and purposes invisible to the end user).

Comment: He wants to accomplish something different: Completely replace the DNS service he’s currently using due to reliability issues.

Comment: @DanielB is right, I have problems with my current provider and want to host the same service on my own dedicated server

Answer (score 0):

DNS servers are expected to have a fixed address which probably kills the idea of hosting it on an every changing IP.
I have been hosting my DNS with zoneedit for years. It supports dynamic DNS and they still offer a free service for up to three low-use domains.